# SQL How to find the Data which is not in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this select statement, where I want to show found and not-found in the result set ...
My query gives me only whatever (values) exists in the DB.
How to also add not-found.
Example:

```
5647994  1234 Data exist in table
5651061  8976 Data exist in table
5823683  null Data not exist in table
6115602  null Data not exist in table

SELECT *
FROM Carrier c
 WHERE (SUBSTRING(c.SrcFileName, 14, 7) in (
'5647994',
'5651061',
'5823683',
'6115602',
'6125795',
'6140114',
'6144781',
'6155133')
```

Comment: you can aways use `NOT IN` the same way you are using `IN`. If you are using a `JOIN` that `LEFT JOIN`  will give you both. We would need to see your table definition and what your SQL is... `is this Microsoft SQL Server`

Comment: left outer join on sub-query will help you

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Thank you for replying quickly. Yes next time I will follow how to.  Sorry about that.
Yes I am using Microsoft SQL Server
Can you please give me example with Left Join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated based upon additional information.

```
If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempSrcFileName') Is Not Null)   Drop Table #TempSrcFileName

CREATE TABLE #TempSrcFileName
(
    src_file_name nchar(7)
)

INSERT INTO #TempSrcFileName (src_file_name)
VALUES
    ('5647994')
    , ('5651061')
    , ('5823683')
    , ('6115602')
    , ('6125795')
    , ('6140114')
    , ('6144781')
    , ('6155133')
;

SELECT
    t.src_file_name
    , 'Found' AS [Status]
FROM #TempSrcFileName t
    LEFT JOIN Carrier c ON SUBSTRING(c.SrcFileName, 14, 7) = t.src_file_name
WHERE   (SUBSTRING(c.SrcFileName, 14, 7) IS NOT NULL)
UNION SELECT
    t.src_file_name
    , 'Not Found' AS [Status]
FROM #TempSrcFileName t
    LEFT JOIN Carrier c ON SUBSTRING(c.SrcFileName, 14, 7) = t.src_file_name
WHERE   (SUBSTRING(c.SrcFileName, 14, 7) IS NULL)
```

Comment: This seems to be the obvious answer, but I think it is wrong. The 2nd part will give you all values in the table that are not in the `in`, but Samant wants to check the values in the `in`... hard to put into words.

Comment: Maraca, yes you are right.  My values that I want to check are in the given set. ONLY '5647994','5651061','5823683','6115602','6125795','6140114','6144781','6155133'.  If these are found then "Found" else "Not Found"

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.val,  
       IF (t2.id IS NULL, 'NOT FOUND', 'FOUND'),
       t2.*
FROM (
  SELECT '5647994' AS val UNION ALL SELECT '5651061' UNION ALL
  SELECT '5823683' UNION ALL SELECT '6115602' UNION ALL 
  SELECT '6125795' UNION ALL SELECT '6140114' UNION ALL
  SELECT '6144781' UNION ALL SELECT '6155133') AS t1
LEFT JOIN Carrier AS t2 ON t1.val = SUBSTRING(t2.SrcFileName, 14, 7)
```

The idea is to create an in-line table that contains all to-be-searched values. If we `LEFT JOIN` the original table to this in-line table, then all values are returned.

The above query assumes that `id` is a field of `Carrier` table. Checking this field for `NULL`/`NOT NULL` values identifies not found / found values respectively.